# Is SHA(-1-2-3) a one to one function for inputs the same length as the output?

Tags: math, hash, cryptography, sha

Is SHA(-1-2-3) a one to one function for inputs the same length as the output?

To restate the question as a concrete example:
SHA-1 has a 160 byte output, so do all 160 byte inputs have unique 160 byte outputs?  Is the answer the same for SHA-2 and 3 and for all available output sizes?

Comment: yes and a million years of cpu time and more storge that anyone has

Comment: user1816847: Yes? You think the SHA functions are one-to-one when their input size is the same as their output size? *REALLY*?!?!

Comment: no i don't know either way.  I'm the OP of the question.  I was responding to someone who said "just write the code to find out it should only take 30 lines" who has since deleted their comment

Comment: Ahh, ok. That makes sense now. LOL ;)

Comment: For such theoretical cryptography questions, [crypto.se](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) is a better fit. We even have a duplicate: [Is SHA-512 bijective when hashing a single 512-bit block?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/301/is-sha-512-bijective-when-hashing-a-single-512-bit-block)

Comment: It seems that [collisions where found](http://cryptome.org/sha1-attacks.htm) for SHA-1, but i didn't test it myself. That would confirm that you don't get unique output, and it was never the idea of a hash function to be collision free.

Comment: @martinstoeckli There is a faster than brute-force method to find collisions in SHA-1, but we didn't actually find any yet. It's also trivial that there are collisions. What's not trivial to prove is that there are collisions for which input and output size are equal. Most likely they exist, but proving it without actually finding a pair is hard.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - You are right, for SHA-1 only 160 byte input strings are part of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nobody knows, because nobody has proven it one way or the other, or tested every possible input at that range. That's the simple truth.

If the functions behaved truly randomly, then the answer would almost certainly be "no" due to the birthday paradox -- on average, you need to test 2^80 inputs to find a collision between any pair, for a 160-bit output.

Comment: has it been proved that it can't be proven other than by exhaustive search?  Has anyone attempted a proof?  Is there anything less strict that can be said?

Comment: @user1816847 If it could be proved either way, then I would stop using it because it's no longer secure.

Comment: @user1816847: No. The mathematical structure of these hash functions is so complex that it is generally hard to prove anything about them at all. (And if you could elegantly wrap them up in a mathematical description, they'd probably be too easy to break).

Comment: @user1816847 Furthermore, they are intentionally complex (with non-mathematical operators like XOR) so that they cannot be figured out.

Comment: interesting.  So if I understand the argument correctly SHA was designed to behave like a random function and not with a 1-1 like property in mind so its very unlikely that it is 1-1 under any reasonable domain.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: While there's no conclusive, definitive answer, I think the *safer* bet (by far if you extend your question to cover *all* the SHA family functions) is to say "**no**". Let's get a *bit* more mathematical.

Let's pick and examine one of the SHA family functions. Assume it returns an *n*-bit output and behaves like a "random oracle" (it doesn't, but assume it) which means it will return a random *n*-bit value for any input with the restriction that will always return the same output for the same input.

With those assumptions, the probability of a collision for any two input strings which are not the same ought to be 2^(-n). Because of the birthday paradox, you would expect to find a collision after about 2^(n/2) distinct inputs.

So because of the birthday paradox, the chances that our function is one-to-one when hashing *n*-bit inputs and generating *n*-bit outputs is not good.

Ultimately, the only way to *conclusively* answer your question would be to try all possible *n*-bit inputs with every possible *n*-bit SHA function. Don't count on getting a definitive answer in your lifetime...